# Why can't I see the programmatically inserted jenkins string parameters in the next groovy build step?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am adding jenkins parameters to a job from system groovy script (one build step):

*1-st step*.

```
import hudson.model.*
def pa = new ParametersAction([
    new StringParameterValue("firstParam", 1), new StringParameterValue("secondParam", 2)
])
Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)
```

Now when I try to execute the next system groovy build step, I am looking for them and they are not there:

*2nd step.*

```
def firstParam = "firstParam"
def secondParam = "secondParam"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def firstParamValue = resolver.resolve(firstParam)
def secondParamValue = resolver.resolve(secondParam)
println firstParamValue
println secondParamValue
```

they both print null! **How do I get the parameters in the next system groovy build step?**

The weird thing is that when I try a shell execution as a following step and if I do:

```
echo $firstParam
echo $secondParam
```

I get both 1 and 2 printed.

Even when I try to print all parameters with the below code I don't get them:

```
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def parameters = build?.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
parameters.each {  
  println "parameter ${it.name}:"
  println it.dump()
  println "-" * 80
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first build step didn't work for me, it gave a runtime error as the string parameters being set are integers not strings. I changed it to this and it works, the second step gets the parameters (I added quotes around integer values & used the 'build' variable for current build):

```
import hudson.model.*

def pa = new ParametersAction([
    new StringParameterValue("firstParam", '1'), new StringParameterValue("secondParam", '2')
])
build.addAction(pa)
```

I am trying this on Jenkins v1.519.

Comment: "Your first build step didn't work for me, it gave a runtime error as the string parameters being set are integers not strings." In reality these parameters are strings. By substituting the real values I mistakenly placed integers, so you might be right. I'll do an edit on that.

Comment: "the second step gets the parameters (I added quotes around integer values & used the 'build' variable for current build)" - were you able to get the variables in another system groovy build step (or in the same build step? Cause I wasn't able to get them with the next system groovy build step (2-nd step.).